# What's an antonym for "protrude"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say there’s an embossed star in a wall (a). If the star’s surface is closer to the viewer than the wall’s surface (b), you can say the star is protruding. Similarly, if the star’s surface is farther from the viewer than the wall’s surface (c), you can say the star is ____.

[image]

Looking for antonyms of “protrude” hasn’t been much helpful.

Here's a sentence showing how it would be used:

> The position of the light source and the shade it casts is what determines in most cases if the star is perceived as protruding or as ______.

The closest I got is "carved in the wall", but that's not quite it. Also, the etymological opposite of *protrude* seems to be *intrude*, but I don't think "the star is intruding" makes sense.

I’m looking for a verb, but adjectives or adverbs would be appreciated too, as long as I can rephrase the sentence so it conveys the meaning I’m after.

Comment: I would use "recede".

Comment: @HotLicks - I thought about recede, but when I looked it up I found that no dictionary defined it like this. Peculiar.

Comment: I would find it quite natural to say "The star recedes into the wall."

Comment: You use "embossed" in your question. Any reason you can't use that?

Comment: @Boluc I wanted something to specifically say the star was receding –just like protrude does–, not merely in relief. I thought "embossed" could be used to describe both the product of a rilievo and that of an intaglio, but as some explained "debossed" specifies a bas-relief and "embossed" a relief. Sure I could use "debossed", but the options I got sound better to me.

Comment: The [CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) calls this "inset", I think.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Consider **recessed**:

> To create or fashion a recess in ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recessed))

A *recess* is defined:

> An indentation or small hollow ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recessed))

Comment: "[Relief printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief_printing) is a process where **protruding** surface faces of the printing plate or block are inked; **recessed** areas are ink free."

Answer (score 27):

You could go with *[indented](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indent)*.

> Indent: make a dent or impression in (something).

Alternatively, you could go with the more technical terms, *embossed* and *[debossed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deboss)*

> Deboss: stamp (a design) into the surface of an object so that it is indented.

Both definitions from OED

Comment: +1 for debossed (a new one to me). If it's embossed, it protrudes.

Comment: emboss was the term I thought about - but I guess *deboss* is more accurate

Answer (score 15):

I think of the verb *sink* or the adjective *sunken*.

Definition of *sunken*:

> At a lower level than the surrounding area.

Example:

> While the auditorium's revolving stage remained, the portal arch was transformed into arched bridges to *sunken*, unroofed parking areas.

Synonyms:

> depressed, deep-set, concave, indented, recessed

(Oxford Dictionaries Online: [sunken](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sunken))

Comment: I'd go with *sunk*: "sunk into the wall". *Sunken in the wall* sounds... lowbrow - for lack of a better term.

Answer (score 6):

I have a strange answer: impress.

In the world of architectural design, I've learned the word "extrude" for 'pulling' a subset of a face out, embossing that subset.  I think of that as the opposite of engrave.

Of course, metaphorically, to leave an impression on someone means to make a mark on them.  Accordingly: I really like the extrude/impress dichotomy.

Similarly, protrude and indent are conceptual antonyms.  Although if you want to conform to conventional usage, these particular options might not be properly understood.

Answer (score 5):

It works better (in my opinion) for text than for the star example, but you could say it had been **engraved** into the wall.

> [**engrave**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/engrave?s=t): to chase (letters, designs, etc.) on a hard surface, as of metal, stone, or the end grain of wood

I would have said there was another option: **"etched"**; but apparently that only applies if chemicals are used for the cutting, rather than an implement.

> [**etch**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/etch?s=t): to cut, bite, or corrode with an acid or the like; engrave with an acid or the like

Answer (score 4):

The most natural word to complete your sentence would be:

> The position of the light source and the shade it casts is what
>   determines in most cases if the star is perceived as protruding or as
>   **receding**.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to say that the star is "depressed" into the wall.

Comment: This answer was already given by Kyle in his synonyms section.

Comment: So were other answers that have been offered.

Answer (score 3):

Consider **Intaglio** that refers to techniques in art in which an image is created by cutting, carving or engraving into a flat surface and may also refer to objects made using these technique.

> Example : [image]

Figure b illustrates a "bas-relief" and the star in figure c, that was "incised in intaglio", is now "displayed in intaglio".

EDIT: @hugh - *After reading the comments, I realized that you already proposed this word. I will delete this answer, if you create one*.

Answer (score 0):

Concave might be the word you are looking for

Comment: The word *concave* (and its opposite *convex*) require a curved transition between the two planes of the object. The illustrations in the Question show a very squared (90 degree) transition between the planes. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concave

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. Why might concave be what they are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

I think incised would also be an option.

Comment: Please give a full answer explaining why.